# Why does Laravel's Response::json return blank if called from another function?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an API using Laravel. I'd like to pass data to a function in the base controller and have the JSON served out via Response::json() from there (the reason for this is so that the response method carries out benchmarking and logging, among other things)

This works:

```
<?php

public function show($id)
{
    $data = Member::find($id);

    return Response::json($data);
}
```

This doesn't:

```
<?php

public function show($id)
{
    $data = Member::find($id);

    $this->respond($data);
}

private function respond($data)
{
    return Response::json($data);
}
```

Can anyone tell me why Response:json() doesn't like being popped into another function?

If I `echo Response::json($data)` instead of `return` it outputs the full response, including the headers.

All input appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try `return $this->respond($data);`?

Comment: Thanks cecilozaur - I'll go and try this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As cecilozaur commented, perhaps you need to:

```
return $this->respond($data);
```

So that the response actually gets returned to the parent function.

Comment: Thanks Simon - I'll go and try that asap.